# Custom Data to State Objects

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i try to prevent access to some route, i use ui-router and i attached a data to my state objects but in some case the run methode retrun an exception "undefined requireLogin"

below is my code

```
angular.module('app', [
'app.user' ])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/main/views/app.html',
            data: {
                requireLogin: true
            }
        })
        // HOME
        .state('app.home', {
            title: 'Home',
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/views/home.html',
            controllers: ['mainController.js'],
        })

})

.run(['$rootScope', '$location',
    function ($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.location = $location;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, current) {



            var requireLogin = current.data.requireLogin;

             if (requireLogin) {
             event.preventDefault();
             $rootScope.location.path('/login');
             }

        });

    }]);
```

and this is my user module

```
angular.module('app.user', [])

.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    var moduleUrl = 'app/modules/user/';
    var moduleTemplate = 'app/main/views/app.html';
    var moduleName = 'app.user';

    $stateProvider
        .state('user', {
            abstract: true,
            data: {
                requireLogin: true,
            },
            url: '/user',
            templateUrl: moduleTemplate,
            resolve: scriptUtils.getResolved(moduleName, [moduleUrl + 'services/userService.js'])
        })

        .state('user.accueil', {
            title: 'user',
            url: '/accueil',
            templateUrl: moduleUrl + 'views/accueil.html',
            controller: 'userController',
            resolve: scriptUtils.getResolved(moduleName,
                [
                    moduleUrl + 'controllers/userController.js'
                ])
        })
        .state('user.add', {
            title: 'user',
            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: moduleUrl + 'views/add.html',
            controller: 'userController',
            resolve: scriptUtils.getResolved(moduleName,
                [
                    moduleUrl + 'controllers/userController.js'
                ])
        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> in some case the run methode retrun an exception "undefined
>   requireLogin"

This may happen in case you have some routes where you didn't include `requireLogin`. To prevent this, do a check first if requireLogin is included in the `data` property.

```
var requireLogin = angular.isDefined(current.data) && current.data.requireLogin;
```

Comment: I included the requireLogin in all the routes but that didn't work in all cases

Answer (score 0):

You dont have requireLogin in all your states.

var requireLogin = current.data ? current.data.requireLogin: false;

Comment: i put it in the parent so that automatically will be included in all the children